# Overloading different types in C++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading

Suppose we have the following class:

```cpp
class Rational { // Represents rational number. n=1/2=d for example.
public:
  int n = 0;
  int d = 1;
};

Rational x = Rational();
x.n = 1;
x.d = 2;
```

Is it possible to do overloading such that `3 * x` would give `3/2` instead of an error?

My teacher said that overloading happens only between objects of the same type, but why can we do overloading between `cout` which is of type `ostream` and an object of type `Rational` and not of the type `int` and `Rational`?

Comment: You need to implement arithmetic operators for your class. See here (look for the "arithmetic" section(s)): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading.

Comment: If you implement the `operator` functions, then you can do `3 * x` and it would do `3 * n / d`

Comment: Re: overloading happens only between objects of the same type. Overloading happens only in functions, and it by definition means taking different number or types or arguments. You surely can overload operator `*` where it takes your class and an integer value

Comment: *"My teacher said that overloading happens only between objects of the same type"*. Your teacher is wrong.

Comment: "My teacher said that overloading happens only between objects of the same type" Either thats not what they said or theyre wrong, also `Rational& operator*(Rational& lhs, float rhs) {lhs.n *= rhs; return lhs; }` seems to do what is asked.

Comment: That looks like a pretty weird `operator*` if it modifies one of its arguments. I'd expect `operator*` to return a `Rational` and `operator*=` to mutate the left hand side and return a `Rational&`.

Comment: Indeed. `*` should normally take a `const Rational &`. Although I can see a benefit of also having `Rational operator *(Rational &&lhs, float rhs)` for e.g. a large matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may write for example

```
Rational operator *( const Rational &r, int x )
{
    return { r.n * x, r.d };
}

Rational operator *( int x, const Rational &r )
{
    return { r.n * x, r.d };
}
```

You may overload operators for user defined types. For a binary operator at least one of operands must be of a user defined type.

From the C++ 20 Standard (12.4.2.3 Operators in expressions)

> 2 **If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a
> user-defined operator function can be declared that implements this
> operator or a user-defined conversion can be necessary to convert the
> operand to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator.** In this
> case, overload resolution is used to determine which operator function
> or built-in operator is to be invoked to implement the operator.
> Therefore, the operator notation is first transformed to the
> equivalent function-call notation as summarized in Table 15 (where @
> denotes one of the operators covered in the specified subclause).
> However, the operands are sequenced in the order prescribed for the
> built-in operator (7.6).

Comment: Thank you. Do I have to write two functions for the case where ```3*x``` and the case ```x*3``` or will one function be enough. I just tried it and it seems like one function is enough, but it's always good to ask.

Comment: @ShinobiSan As the operator is commutative then you should to define the both operators.

Comment: I didn't really understand, if it is commutative then one function should be enough right?

Comment: @ShinobiSan Not enough. That is if you will overload the operator for the expression 3 * x then for the expression x * 3 the compiler will issue an error because there is no such an operator for this order of arguments of these types.

Comment: C++ overload resolution doesn't assume that `*` is commutative. (It isn't, always.) So if you have `operator*(const Rational&, int)` but not `operator*(int, const Rational&)` and you try to write `3 * someRational`, the compiler will not attempt to go "I don't know what this means, but would I be able to do something if I tried `someRational * 3` instead?"

Comment: @ShinobiSan One could (and should) implement the function logic only once, and refer to this one implementation also in the second function wwhich applies for interchanged parameters.

Comment: Yeah I'd suggest that in Vlad's answer the second function should just read `return r * x;`